# How to redirect the page from www.example.com/about.php to www.example.com/beta/about.php using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have used the following code,

**RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/beta/$1 [R=301,L]**

but it redirect only www.example.com  to www.example.com/beta/

i want to redirect 
www.example.com/about.php to www.example.com/beta/about.php?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check the top right of the page. There's a search box, learn to use it, learn to love it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/beta/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So, it would redirect anything **but** `example.com/about.php` ...