# How to redirect page by using .htaccess

Tags: url, redirect, rule

I am using given below code to redirect to login page,When enter url in address bar e.g.(exmple.com/web/) then redirect to "http://exmple.com/web/login.php" How ?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exmple.com/web/$

RewriteRule ^$ http://exmple.com/web/login.php [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.exmple\.com$
        RewriteRule ^$ http://www.exmple.com/web/login.php[L,R=301]
```

Comment: check this   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13524490/how-to-redirect-the-page-from-www-example-com-about-php-to-www-example-com-beta?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

%{HTTP_HOST} variable represents the current domain name without the path segment . Your RewriteCond is invalid because it is trying to match **example.com/web/** as domain name which is a non existent domain and the RewriteCond fails.

Change the following condition :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^exmple.com/web$
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exmple.com$
```

You can use the following :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?exmple.com$
RewriteRule ^(web/?)?$ http://exmple.com/web/login.php [L,R=301]
```

You can also use  RedirectMatch in your htaccess to redirect an url to a diffrent location :

```
RedirectMatch ^/web/?$ http://exmple.com/web/login.php
```

Clear your browser's cache before testing these solutions.